# Some questions about memory/malloc

Tags: c, variables, malloc

How are variables really stored in memory? I ask this because say you malloc a segment of memory and assign it to a pointer e.g.

```
int *p = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

and then run a for loop to assign integers through p - this seems different to declaring an int variable and assigning an integer to it like:

```
int x = 10;
```

Because it's a more explicit declaration that you want an int stored in memory, whereas in malloc it's just a chunk of memory you're traversing through pointer arithmetic.

Am I missing something here? Much thanks.

Comment: Well, because the answer was deleted, I summarize it here again for you: malloc() returns a raw chunk of data, which isn't preserved for any type. Even if you assign it to an int lvalue the data chunk isn't of type int, untill you derefference it as thoose. (means you'r using it with data of a special type.) The chunk you are getting is described by the parameter parsed to the function in Bytes. sizeof() represents the size of the type.

Comment: so you are getting in this case a chunk that has place for 10 integers. but if you havent used it with the int * ptr, you could also asign the address to a pointer of type char, and use the block as memory block for 40 char values. But the first time you "put something in there" its then preserved for that type. I'll put this in my answer for you too ;)

Comment: much appreciated for the effort @Zaibis!

Answer (score 1):

when you need an array of data, for example when you receive numbers from the user but don't know the length you can't use a fixed number of integers, you need a dynamic way to crate memory for those integers. `malloc` and his friends let you do that. among other things:

- malloc let you create memory dynamically in the size you need right now.
- while using malloc the memory will **not** be freed when exiting the scope.
- using malloc for let's say array of 10 item or create an array of 10 items on the stack there is no difference in the sense of " explicit declaration that you want an int stored in memory", there is just differences in what i've written here and some more

[here](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html) is an article on the differences between heap and stack

i'm writing the pros of each way:

**Stack**

- very fast access
- don't have to explicitly de-allocate variables
- space is managed efficiently by CPU, memory will not become fragmented
- local variables only
- limit on stack size (OS-dependent)
- variables cannot be resized

**Heap**

- variables can be accessed globally
- no limit on memory size
- (relatively) slower access
- no guaranteed efficient use of space, memory may become fragmented over time as blocks of memory are allocated, then freed
- you must manage memory (you're in charge of allocating and freeing variables)
- variables can be resized using realloc()

Comment: limit on stack size (OS-dependent) not completly true... also depending on compiler!

Comment: @Zaibis thank you for the addition, but it's also written - OS-depended

Answer (score 0):

malloc asigns an memoryblock and returns an pointer to it, its life time is as of dynamicaly allocated memory. You can store any objects of its type in it.
An int

```
int x = 10;
```

is automatic storage and is an lvalue not an pointer.
So you dont have to access it by it's adress, as you would have to by an value a pointer is pointing to.
You can access and assign it's value by it's identifyer name.
And its also cleaned up, when you leave it's scope.

I summarize your questions about from the deleted answer here again for you: malloc() returns a raw chunk of data, which isn't preserved for any type. Even if you assign it to an int lvalue the data chunk isn't of type int, untill you derefference it as thoose. (means you'r using it with data of a special type.) The chunk you are getting is described by the parameter parsed to the function in Bytes. sizeof() represents the size of the type.
    so you are getting in this case a chunk that has place for 10 integers. but if you havent used it with the int * ptr, you could also asign the address to a pointer of type char, and use the block as memory block for 40 char variables. But the first time you "put something in there" its then preserved for that type.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared in C like `int x = 10` are located on the stack, which is accessible only until the function it's declared in returns (if it's declared outside functions, we call it global, and it's available through the whole runtime of the application).

Memory allocated with `malloc` and similar functions are located in the heap, which is accessible either until it's freed explicitly (e.g. calling `free(...)`) or the application terminates (which in case of servers might take weeks/months/years).

Both the stack and the heap is part of the memory, the main difference is in the method of allocation. In C, the `*` and `&` unary operators can blur the line between the two, so for example in case of a declaration like `int x = 10` you can get the address like `int* y = &x`, and at the same time, you can assign a value like `*y = 15` in case of a pointer as well.

Comment: You cant know they will be located on the stack or anywhere else! same about the heap.

Comment: In theory, you're right, however, I've yet to see a mainstream compiler producing code that didn't put local variables in the stack.

Comment: `int x = 10;` is not necessarily a local variable.  It could be global and thus have static storage.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you're doing

```
            int x = 10;
```

Compiler does whatever needs to be done. But when you're using malloc(), you're in charge of maintaining that memory block, you can use it at your wish, this also gives you the burdon of cleaning it up properly.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you know the array size .  Use `int array[10]` is faster and more safe than `int *array = malloc(10*sizeof(int))` . Only if you didn.t know the size before run-time then you need `malloc` thing.

2.The declare `int x = 10` ,  `x` stored in stack memory. If you declare `int *p = malloc(10*sizeof(int));` the `p` is stored in stack memory but the memory `p` pointer is in heap.

3.When you use `int *p = malloc(10*sizeof(int));` , the function alloc a block memory , it only have the right size. In fact you can store type you want in this memory , thoungh not encourage to do this.

4.If you use `int x = 10` , the memory will be freed auto , just after the variable out of its scope. If you use `malloc`, you should free the memory by yourself,or memory leak!

Comment: And again i have got to say YOU CANT KNOW its really going to be stored on stack heap or wether...

Comment: @Zaibis You make me stucked . How can we don't know ?

Comment: Because the compiler has to decide it in last instance. We can just assume to put it there or here, or where ever.

Comment: @Zaibis Can you show me any kind of authority link ? You just destory my belief!

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899 There isn't anything mentioned how it has to be stored. So there exists no rule about, where it has to get placed. The pendantic part is, the compiler just has to decide where its most effective in respect of the lifetime rules.